# Open a new view when tapping a UITextField (Round Style Text Field)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, segue

I'm trying to open a Table View Controller when I tap a UITextField. 
I added a push segue to my UITextField. However, rather than switching to 
the new view, a keypad is opening.

What can be the problem?

Comment: A similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976487/how-to-navigate-to-next-uiviewcontroller-using-uitextview-in-an-uinavigationbar/18976596#18976596

Answer (score 3):

1st in your .m file declare the UITextView delegate:

```
 @interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
 self.textField.delegate = self;
```

Implement the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method:

```
 - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {
       //segue over here
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try implementing the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`  `UITextViewDelegate` method. It would look something like:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == myTextField) {
        // Open the new ViewController here

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

You also have to set the delegate: `myTextField.delegate = self;`

Comment: You should not be returning anything... It is a void method.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique no it's not, that is what that `- (BOOL)` part is for

Answer (score 1):

you need to check out the `UItapGestureRecognizer`. you need to add TapGesture Recognizer on textField when user tapped on `textField`. then call tapGestureRecognizer method and do what you want here.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * recog=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];

    recog.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    recog.delegate=self;

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recog];


    -(void)tapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
    {

      // Do what you want here

    }
```

2) 2nd way is

add TextField delegatei in .h file.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {
        //Do what you want here..
  }
```

try this one...